# Create remote branch from master

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to create a remote branch called "development" from the remote "master".

Essentially duplicating remote "master" and name it "development"

What is the simple way to do this?

I am using Bitbucket

Comment: 1) Clone "master" locally.  2) Create new branch, e.g. `git checkout -b development`, 3) Push

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository:

```
$ git clone <repo_url>
```

Create new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b development
```

Push the new branch:

```
$ git push -u origin development
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.